# Certificate Authority in Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Sawtooth

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, certificate-authority, hyperledger-sawtooth

Does Hyperledger Sawtooth have any component that performs an action similar to what Fabric CA does in Hyperledger Fabric?

In case it does not have, can I make use of any such external component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Hyperledger Sawtooth does not have a CA. One can use any identity software one wishes to use.

Examples of open source identity software include
* Hyperledger Indy (blockchain-based Identity software)
* Apache Synscope (based on the Sun Identity Manager)
* OpenIDM
* Gluu

Comment: could you provide some example of identity software that could be used with Sawtooth as painless as possible? Or some link to any related docs.

Comment: another thing, is it mandatory to use a CA to identify to identify actors? and where Indy could be placed in this process...? Sawtooth NEXT Identity Platform too. It's a bit hard to figure out the big picture.